# Слово категории состояния — часть речи или нет?

Tags: части-речи

Добрый день. Интересует вопрос: какие есть авторитетные источники, подтверждающие, что СКС — это отдельная часть речи? Справочник какой-нибудь новый от РАН, постановление? В общем, на что можно ссылаться при возникновении споров? Заранее спасибо.

P.S. И тот же вопрос по поводу причастия и деепричастия. Прекрасно помню, что у Бабайцевой они были выделены в отдельные части речи, хотя на тот момент в некоторых других источниках считались особыми формами глагола.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В книге Рахимкуловой «Морфология современного русского языка» (учебник для вузов 2009 года) дается краткий анализ всех частей речи, в том числе слов категории состояния.

В первой половине 19 века в трудах отечественных лингвистов выделяется разряд слов, которые по форме совпадают с существительными, прилагательными, наречиями, но имеют значение состояния и употребляются в качестве сказуемого в безличных предложениях. Такие слова стали называть категориями состояния (СКС), или предикативами, или безлично-предикативными словами.

В общей классификации частей речи положение СКС определяется неоднозначно, существуют два основных подхода: а) СКС – это самостоятельная часть речи (Щерба, Виноградов): б) СКС – это наречия на особых правах (Щерба  и другие).

В  частности в академической Грамматике-80 СКС самостоятельной частью речи не считаются (они называются предикативными наречиями и модальными предикативами), в то же время в вузовской практике СКС рассматриваются в качестве особой части речи, совмещающей свойства глагола и наречия.

Причастия и деепричастия считаются формами глагола. В Грамматике-80 указывается, что это атрибутивные формы глагола, совмещающие свойства глагола и прилагательного или наречия.
Причастия и деепричастия сохраняют многие свойства глагола (вид, залог, переходность, возвратность, управление, время или отношение к временному фактору), но имеют другую словоизменительную систему и другую синтаксическую функцию.

Answer (score 3):

В науке этот вопрос до сих пор остается дискуссионным. Академические грамматики русского языка слова категории состояния как особую часть речи не выделяют.  Спорен и вопрос, что туда относить.

В.В. Виноградов включал в категорию состояния:

1) краткие прилагательные, утратившие свои полные формы: рад, должен; 2) краткие страдательные причастия: угнетен, взволнован; 3) безлично-предикативные слова на -о: радостно, грустно; 4) бывшие существительные: лень, грех, стыд и т.д.

А.Н. Тихонов объединяет в категорию состояния неизменяемые слова со значением состояния, которые со связкой употребляются в качестве сказуемого в безличном предложении и в двусоставном предложении со сказуемым-инфинитивом*.

Е.М. Галкина-Федорук ограничивает круг слов, образующих категорию состояния только теми словами, которые выступают в роли сказуемого в безличном предложении.

Концепция Е.М. Галкиной-Федорук получила свое развитие в работах Н.А. Каламовой, точка зрения которой излагается в вузовских учебникеах.Например:СОВРЕМЕННЫЙ РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК.ЛЕКСИКА. ФРАЗЕОЛОГИЯ. МОРФОЛОГИЯ. РАХМАНОВА Л.И.,СУЗДАЛЬЦЕВА В.Н. 
М.: Из-дво МГУ, Издательство «ЧеРо», 1997
Пособие адресовано прежде всего студентам факультетов и отделений журналистики университетов. Может быть использовано и студентами гуманитарных отделений педагогических вузов.

В школе по основной программе категория состояния разбирается как отдельная часть речи, причастие и деепричастие -как глагольные формы. Только Бабайцева разбирает **все** эти категории слов как самостоятельные части речи, но она стоит особняком. В ЕГЭ нет такого задания,где бы это пригодилось, главное, чтобы нашли такие слова.К категории состояния относят в школе, как и в вузе, слова, отражающие состояние человека, окружающей среды, оценку действий, которые являются **сказуемым в безличном предложении**, они омонимичны наречиям

Comment:  Странно, не припоминаю, чтобы Бабайцева выделяла СКС в качестве отдельной части речи. Надо освежить в памяти учебник.

Answer (score 0):

Всегда становился в тупик от запросов типа "Докажите что это называется так, а не этак".
А уж "постановление"... Это убивает. Чье постановление? О чем? Мало, что или нам иди... гм... умных голов, узаконивших в Думе ныне и присно список матерных слов?

Считаю, что подобные споры бессодержательны изначально. Что вообще такое классификация по частям речи? Некоторая составляющая модели грамматики, вещь весьма субъективная. Моджно так грамматику описвать, можно этак. И все системы быдут справедливы ровно настолько, насколько они внутренне непротиворечивы. А пользоваться можно той, которая удобнее. 
Но удобство - не доказательство. К тому же всегда надо понимать, что то, что "удобно" в школе, в академической грамматике может оказаться совершенно инородным...

По сути - у Vera есть все. Выбирайте любую систему, только будьте последовательными, взяв что-то у условной Бабайцевой, если надергать кусков из разных подходов то получится полная каша с кучей внутренних противоречий. Отсюда и ваши вопросы.

Мне лично, академический подход ближе в том смысле, что в основу положен принцип, который я бы охарактеризовал как семантический: все основные части речи делится на две большие группы: имя (объект-субъект) и действие. А уж внутри этих групп происходит конкретизация. Вся структура такой модели грамматики (кроме служебных и междометий) сразу обозрима.

А по Бабайцевой вместо цельной грамматики получается набор плохо структурированных, почти атомарных, составляющих... 
Но это ж не для школьников разговоры... Им-то Бабайцева будет и понятнее и полезнее...

Comment: @behemothus, во-первых, мои "запросы" взяты не с потолка, а связаны в первую очередь с конкретными явлениями жизни — экзаменами и иными контрольно-проверочными мероприятиями. К какой части речи на ЕГЭ должен отнести школьник слово "холодно" (в предложении "стало холодно") — наречию или СКС? От сего зависит его будущее. Во-вторых, мои вопросы не из-за неоднородности "систем". Моя точка зрения на части речи однозначна и консервативна: их 10, причастия/деепричастия, СКС, модальные слова не выделяются. Но оказалось, она неактуальна в рамках преподавания на журфаке УрФО (по учебнику Майдановой).

Comment: >во-первых, мои "запросы" взяты не с потолка  
  
Разве я высказывал в том сомнения?  
    
>К какой части речи на ЕГЭ   
  
Я давным-давно сказал, что ЕГЭ - не моя епархия. Во-первых потому, что я никаким боком к преподаванию не отношусь, да и с русскиям язвком ни по образованию, ни по работе никогда связан не был. А во-вторых, преподаватели сами в шоке от таких вопросов.    
  
Тут скорее надо ставить вопрос, как обмануть эту самую ЕГУ, дав ответ устраивающий всех... Но его нет. Поэтому все что могу посоветовать: следуйте Бабайцевой и следите за методичками.

Comment: @behemothus, я объяснил подоплёку своего вопроса, а не соотносил "епархию" ЕГЭ с вами. 

>>Поэтому все что могу посоветовать: следуйте Бабайцевой и следите за методичками.

 Спасибо, конечно, но конкретно я в советах по сдаче ЕГЭ не нуждаюсь уже давно. За детей переживаю.

Comment: Не бывает в ЕГЭ таких вопросов.

Comment: @Niemand, а если будет? Дело не конкретно в ЕГЭ, а в отсутствии общего стандарта.

Comment: Ну, не надо делать из ЕГЭ такого монстра. Вопросов с неоднозначными ответами в нем нет — это же не филфак.

А общего стандарта нет, потому что естественный язык — штука сложная и неточная. Вот в языках программирования точные стандарты есть. И любая система программирования отвечает стандарту процентов на 95-97 (но тоже не на сто!)

Comment: >я объяснил подоплёку своего вопроса, а не соотносил "епархию" ЕГЭ с вами.   
  
Я тоже с Вами ничего не соотносил и объяснил своё понимание.   
Если лично Вы не нуждаетесь, то зачем спрашиваете? Объясните детям - и да будет вам "щщастье". Или передайте им то, что вам сказал. Какой еще вариант можно предложить? Я такого не знаю.  
  
Людмила вон все по полочкам разложила. Я могу только лайк поставить.

Comment: @behemothus, я спросил про ЕГЭ, дабы обрисовать примерную ситуацию. Людмила, действительно, всё разложила, не тратя зазря буквы на сетования. Всем бы так.

@Niemand, настолько сложная и неточная, что даже с частями речи не могут определиться на школьном уровне? Увы, не считаю это нормальной ситуацией. Как уже говорил, ЕГЭ было приведено просто в качестве примера.

Comment: На школьном уровне всё нормально, никаких коллизий нет.